# Отменить налог в заказе (без использования woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

пытаюсь отменить налог в заказе. Нужно, что бы set_is_vat_exempt происходил во время оформления заказа и действовал на текущий заказ, а не только на последующие. Через init это невозможно сделать.
Буду благодарен, если кто подскажет хук или другое решение, которые могут заменить init (кроме woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review).

```
add_action( 'init', 'wc_tax_exempt' );
function wc_tax_exempt_unlogged() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $woocommerce->customer->set_is_vat_exempt(FALSE);
    $cur_user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $tax_exempt = get_user_meta( $cur_user_id, 'tax_exempt', true );
    if( $tax_exempt == 1){
        $woocommerce->customer->set_is_vat_exempt(true);  
    }
}
```